# Button ClickListener is not working in LibGDX game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing an Android game using LibGDX. There are 4 buttons in a menu screen, but the `ClickListener` of these buttons is not working.

```
// retrieve the custom skin for our 2D widgets
Skin skin = super.getSkin();

// create the table actor and add it to the stage
table = new Table( skin );
table.width = stage.width();
table.height = stage.height();
stage.addActor( table );

// retrieve the table's layout
TableLayout layout = table.getTableLayout();

// register the button "start game"
TextButton startGameButton = new TextButton( "Start game", skin );
startGameButton.addListener( new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        System.out.println("hiii");
        Assets.load();
        // game.getSoundManager().play( TyrianSound.CLICK );
        game.setScreen( new GameScreen(game) );
    }
} );

layout.register( "startGameButton", startGameButton );
```

How to activate the `ClickListener` of a button in LibGDX?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to add the button to the stage and call

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Answer (score 21):

Instead of "click method" now it's "clicked method" (I think!), just in case someone faces the same problem I was facing when found this question:

```
startGameButton.addListener( new ClickListener() {              
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        game.setScreen( new GameScreen(game) );
    };
});
```

Comment: It is now clicked as the method name, with a lower-case "c" to start.

Comment: Additionally, now it is `startGameButton.addListener`