# What is the simplest way to make Image touchable in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
super.resize(width, height);

stage.clear();

// background image
Image backImage = new Image(backTexture);
backImage.setX(0);
backImage.setY(0);
backImage.setWidth(800);
backImage.setHeight(480);

// start game image
Image startImage = new Image(startTexture);
startImage.setX(415);
startImage.setY(180);
startImage.setWidth(323);
startImage.setHeight(69);

stage.addActor(backImage);
stage.addActor(startImage);
}
```

I'm creating simple game and this is the way I'm creating main menu. I want to make my startImage touchable (clickable) as there is no available listener for Image class. How should I do this? Or is it better to use ImageButton? This way I would have to create image atlas which seems to be a little bit complicated for me now..

EDIT:
I tried following:

```
startImage.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
    {
        game.setScreen(new SplashScreen(game));
        return true;
    }
});
```

But it still doesn't work..

EDIT:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

needs to be called. Solved.

Comment: Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373390/button-clicklistener-is-not-working-in-libgdx-game


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373390/button-clicklistener-is-not-working-in-libgdx-game

Comment: Please provide your solution as an "answer" and accept it.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution is to call following:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```